# Loop through the meta value of WooCommerce products using a WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working in WooCommerce API and I would like to make a new endpoint which lists me specific products. We have made previously new fields with a plugin and I would like to check them. If the property is ticked in the settings, then show it, else do not.

The new property of the products (checkbox in advanced settings):

```
woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id'        => '_checkbox_badge_hot',
            'desc'      =>  __('set the checkbox', 'woocommerce'),
            'label'     => __('Hot', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip'  => 'true',
            'value'     => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_checkbox_badge_hot', true )
        )
    );
```

The Code which should list me the products (now if I try to request to the endpoint it just keeps loading):

```
function get_hot_products(){
    $args_for_hot_product = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1                       
    );  
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args_for_hot_product );
    $hotproducts = [];
    
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(){
        $hot = $loop->get_meta('_checkbox_badge_hot');
        if( $hot === "yes" ){
            array_push($hotproducts, $hot);
        }
    }
    //wp_reset_postdata();
    return $hotproducts;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( '/wc/v3', '/featuredproducts', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_hot_products',
  ) );
} );
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get and display all products that have a specific custom field value, using a `WP_Query`, you will simply use a eta query as follow:

```
function display_hot_products(){
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => array( array(
            'key'        => '_checkbox_badge_hot',
            'value'      => 'yes',
            'compare'    => '=',
        )),
    ));

    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    the_title(); // Display product title

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Don't forget that when using a `WP_Query` you get `WC_Post` objects and not `WC_Product` Objects.